# Tkinter and PIL interfering with each other (Image.open) in Python

Tags: python-3.x, image, tkinter

keep in mind I am just showing a small part of the code.

Without Tkinter being imported the code below works:

```
import os
import PIL
from PIL import ImageTk, Image
import cv2
import numpy as np
import pytesseract
import pandas as pd

##CROPS NUMBER PLATE
diretory_save_cut_out_NP = main_folder_directory + '/' + 'Computational directory/NP & VIN/Original NP/'

for x in range(0, file_count):
    im = Image.open(original_file_directory + reg_doc_list_names[0] + '.png')
    x1 = 140
    y1 = 740
    x2 = im.width - 1200
    y2 = im.height - 2470 
    region = im.crop((x1, y1, x2, y2))
    region.save(diretory_save_cut_out_NP + reg_doc_list_names[0] + '.png')
    reg_doc_list_names.pop(0)
```

However if I import Tkinter and try to make a GUI this error pops out:

```
import os
import PIL
from PIL import ImageTk, Image
import cv2
import numpy as np
import pytesseract
import pandas as pd
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import *

    ##CROPS NUMBER PLATE
    diretory_save_cut_out_NP = main_folder_directory + '/' + 'Computational directory/NP & VIN/Original NP/'

    for x in range(0, file_count):
        im = Image.open(original_file_directory + reg_doc_list_names[0] + '.png')
        x1 = 140
        y1 = 740
        x2 = im.width - 1200
        y2 = im.height - 2470 
        region = im.crop((x1, y1, x2, y2))
        region.save(diretory_save_cut_out_NP + reg_doc_list_names[0] + '.png')
        reg_doc_list_names.pop(0)

Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\lol\Anaconda3\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1883, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "<ipython-input-11-a57cb1712307>", line 35, in scanner
    im = Image.open(original_file_directory + reg_doc_list_names[0] + '.png')
AttributeError: type object 'Image' has no attribute 'open'
```

I've tried a few things, however nothing worked, do you guys have any recommendations? Thanks in advance, Ill try and respond as quick as poossible.

Comment: You are using `tkinter.Image()`, not `PIL.Image()` due to `from tkinter import *`.

Comment: @acw1668 mate you're great, its working now, thank you

Comment: `*` imports aren't always evil but they're misused a lot. `import tkinter as tk` is much better if you really need a lot of the `tk` stuff as it doesn't pollute your namespace with potential conflicts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Code that works, thanks to @acw1668:

```
##CROPS NUMBER PLATE
diretory_save_cut_out_NP = main_folder_directory + '/' + 'Computational directory/NP & VIN/Original NP/'

for x in range(0, file_count):
    im = PIL.Image.open(original_file_directory + reg_doc_list_names[0] + '.png')
    x1 = 140
    y1 = 740
    x2 = im.width - 1200
    y2 = im.height - 2470 
    region = im.crop((x1, y1, x2, y2))
    region.save(diretory_save_cut_out_NP + reg_doc_list_names[0] + '.png')
    reg_doc_list_names.pop(0)
```

Comment: btw that is the reason to not use `*` when importing unless certain, otherwise just import what You need, like `from tkinter import Tk, Label, Button` and so on